# Informatica - Create & email a flat file if records exist, otherwise complete successfully

Tags: informatica

Hello everyone and thanks for taking the time to read this question!

What I am trying to do in Informatica is populate and email a file based on a sql query. So right now I have

DB source table ----> SQ w/ query -----> flat file target (emails flat file to me every time) in a single session workflow.

What I would like to do is ONLY email the file if it has records.  I also don't want to the workflow to fail if there are no records and no email is sent.  Just go on it's merry way and wait for the next run.

Thank You!

Comment: Are you using an email task to send email?

Answer (score 0):

Should be simple.
Create two sessions/mappings like this -

- session 1 - Read using your SQL and write data into a dummy file.
- session 2 - Depending on target success row of session1 this will run. Link condition should be - if Session1.TgtSuccessRows>0 then run session2. Add your mail id on session2's success e mail. You can use any dummy mapping here.

Please note you can use email task instead of session2.

Koushik